# Bootstrap Table Javascript Total Sum Become NaN?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, bootstrap-4, html-table

I created a table using bootstrap, The Data links with phpmyadmin. I am require to display the total of current amount in the table. As i filter using a search function, The data of the amount should change as well. But my result keep showing NaN.

Here are my code :

```
// PART OF CODE //
<script>
var sumVal = 0;
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    if (td) {
        sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML);   
    }
}
document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = " :" + sumVal;
console.log(sumVal);
</script>
// PART OF CODE  //
...
<table class="table table-sm table-hover mb-0" id="myTable">
...
<!-- <span id="val"></span> -->
```

[Rendered Html Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBm0W.png)

Any solutions to this problem ?

Comment: show us html of the table.

Comment: @Kharel Added the part of html of the table.

Comment: Add your rendered html. Whole table, At least 2 records.

Comment: as Mr/Ms. @Thapa said add atleast 2 records

Comment: @Thapa Added the rendered html.

Comment: Just use [`sum()`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()) plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    content = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    sumVal += parseInt(content.innerHTML);     
}

document.getElementById("val").innerHTML =  sumVal;
console.log(sumVal);
```